# Autoresize UIView in Xamarin.iOS ViewRenderer

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, autoresize

I'm trying to create a camera view. Basically a View that represents the camera input.

Right now, I'm having a **ViewRenderer** render a **UIView** to a **Xamarin.Forms.View**.

in the OnElementChanged I have the following lines:

```
if(Control == null)
{
    var uiView = new UIView(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds)
                {
                    AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight,
                    AutosizesSubviews = true
                };
}
```

This makes my UIView fit the whole screen (which is what I want).

But on rotation changes, the UIView does not resize and the preview is flipped. How do you guys approach this?
I don't seem to be looking in the correct direction, as I do not find a simple solution to make an UIView resize on orientation changes or even resize orientation changed events.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
The UIView actually resizes, I don't even have to set the two mentioned properties in my question.

The thing that was not resizing was the attached `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.
So I resize it accordingly in the overriden LayoutSubviews() of my ViewRenderer implementation:

```
    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        previewLayer.Frame = Bounds; //Important to resize the preview layer so it fits the whole screen on orientation change
    }
```